# How to use DisconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages in Android MQTT?

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

This is about paho MQTT client for Android: The Javadoc for `DisconnectedBufferOptions` does not specify the exact behavior of `setDeleteOldestMessages()`. If I set it to `false` and there are more messages than the buffer can hold, what will be the outcome ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Paho source code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/DisconnectedMessageBuffer.java):

```
/**
 * This will add a new message to the offline buffer,
 * if the buffer is full and deleteOldestMessages is enabled
 * then the 0th item in the buffer will be deleted and the
 * new message will be added. If it is not enabled then an
 * MqttException will be thrown.
 * @param message the {@link MqttWireMessage} that will be buffered
 * @param token the associated {@link MqttToken}
 * @throws MqttException if the Buffer is full
 */
public void putMessage(MqttWireMessage message, MqttToken token) throws MqttException{
    BufferedMessage bufferedMessage = new BufferedMessage(message, token);
    synchronized (bufLock) {
        if(buffer.size() < bufferOpts.getBufferSize()){
            buffer.add(bufferedMessage);
        } else if(bufferOpts.isDeleteOldestMessages() == true){
            buffer.remove(0);
            buffer.add(bufferedMessage);
        }else {
            throw new MqttException(MqttException.REASON_CODE_DISCONNECTED_BUFFER_FULL);
        }
    }
}
```